# How to combine two sql select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have two SQL select statement that says

```
SELECT TOP (150) FoodID, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfFood FROM FoodTable WHERE FoodID IS NOT NULL AND FoodDate >= '2015-10-01' GROUP BY FoodID ORDER BY NumberOfFood DESC
```

I also have another SQL statement

```
SELECT FoodSellerID, Market1, SellerLastName, SellerFirstName, PrimaryAddress1, PrimaryAddress2, PrimaryCity, PrimaryState, PrimaryZip FROM SellerTable, MarketTable 
WHERE Market1= MarketTable.MarketID
```

Few notes to point out, FoodID lookup to SellerTable, Market1  Lookup to MarketTable. My question is how can I combine both and return the tables like

FoodID  |   NumberofFood    |   SellerLastName  |   SellerFirstName |   PrimaryAddress1 |   PrimaryAddress2 |   PrimaryCity |   PrimaryState|   PrimaryZip

Comment: Please format your queries, it's completely unreadable now.

Comment: Please tag the relevant DBMS only

Comment: You should start using the ANSI-92 style joins...they have been around now for more than 25 years. This means using the join keyword and not using the equals predicate in your where statement.

Comment: How do the queries relate? Can you get `FoodID` from any of the tables in the 2nd query?

Comment: This would be pretty easy to help if you posted the definition of the tables. I don't see anything in what you posted that would let you know what FoodID belongs with a given row in your second query. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks for your comment I eventually got it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manny, you won't be able to join these two queries without some common field in both.  If you have a common field, then you could build each as a temp table and join them with a third query. It looks like you have 'Food ID' in the FoodTable (from the first query).  If that exists on the SellerTable, then you could join the two (and also join the MarketTable to get rows from that table).

That would look something like this:

```
    create temp table food_nums_temp as 
    SELECT TOP (150) FoodID, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfFood 
    FROM FoodTable 
    WHERE FoodID IS NOT NULL 
    AND FoodDate >= '2015-10-01'
    GROUP BY FoodID 
    ORDER BY NumberOfFood DESC
    ; 

    Create temp table seller_temp as
    SELECT FoodSellerID, FoodID,
    Market1,
    SellerLastName, 
    SellerFirstName, 
    PrimaryAddress1, 
    PrimaryAddress2, 
    PrimaryCity, 
    PrimaryState,
    PrimaryZip 
    FROM SellerTable, MarketTable 
    WHERE Market1= MarketTable.MarketID
    ;

    select a.*, b.SellerLastName  
    , b.SellerFirstName, b.PrimaryAddress1, b.PrimaryAddress2
    , b.PrimaryCity, b.PrimaryState, b.PrimaryZip
    from food_nums_temp a
    inner join seller_temp b on a.FoodID = b.FoodID
```

EDIT: knowing that full db access (create temp table) is not allowed, lets use 'WITH' (aka common table expressions or CTE) to stage our data  prior to our desired query:

```
    with 
    food_nums_temp as (
    SELECT TOP (150) FoodID, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfFood 
    FROM FoodTable 
    WHERE FoodID IS NOT NULL 
    AND FoodDate >= '2015-10-01'
    GROUP BY FoodID 
    ORDER BY NumberOfFood DESC
    ),       

    seller_temp as
    SELECT FoodSellerID, FoodID,
    Market1,
    SellerLastName, 
    SellerFirstName, 
    PrimaryAddress1, 
    PrimaryAddress2, 
    PrimaryCity, 
    PrimaryState,
    PrimaryZip 
    FROM SellerTable, MarketTable 
    WHERE Market1= MarketTable.MarketID
    )

    select a.*, b.SellerLastName  
    , b.SellerFirstName, b.PrimaryAddress1, b.PrimaryAddress2
    , b.PrimaryCity, b.PrimaryState, b.PrimaryZip
    from food_nums_temp a
    inner join seller_temp b on a.FoodID = b.FoodID
```

Comment: Note that I don't have access to full DB, I have view only, and I'm trying to pull data from three different tables....

Comment: Manny, I edited the answer to use Common Table Expressions (CTE, accompished using keyword 'WITH') to stage our data up prior to the query.  Please see the above.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your vague description of **FoodID lookup to SellerTable**, try this

```
SELECT FoodSellerID, 
       Market1,
       SellerLastName, 
       SellerFirstName, 
       PrimaryAddress1, 
       PrimaryAddress2, 
       PrimaryCity, 
       PrimaryState,
       PrimaryZip 
FROM SellerTable ST
INNER JOIN MarketTable MT
  ON ST.Market1 = MT.MarketID
inner join 
    (
    SELECT FoodID, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfFood 
    FROM FoodTable 
    WHERE FoodID IS NOT NULL 
    AND FoodDate >= '2015-10-01'
    GROUP BY FoodID 
    ) a1
  on a1.FoodID = ST.FoodID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this:

```
SELECT TOP (150) a.FoodID, COUNT(*) AS a.NumberOfFood,b.SellerLastName, b.SellerFirstName, b.PrimaryAddress1, b.PrimaryAddress2, b.PrimaryCity, b.PrimaryState, b.PrimaryZipFROM FoodTable a inner join SellerTable b on a.FoodID = b.FoodSellerID WHERE a.Market1= b.MarketTable.MarketID IS NOT NULL AND FoodDate >= '2015-10-01' GROUP BY a.FoodID, b.SellerLastName, b.SellerFirstName, b.PrimaryAddress1, b.PrimaryAddress2, b.PrimaryCity, 
b.PrimaryState, b.PrimaryZip ORDER BY a.NumberOfFood DESC
```

Note: Could be another solution.